# How to export Visual Studio Code Color Scheme to JetBrains IDEs (for example, CLion)?

Tags: visual-studio-code, clion, jetbrains-ide

I really love Atom One Dark theme shown in the picture. I would really like to export that to have it in its full form in CLion. Is this possible? Because that theme in CLion's marketplace doesn't have coloring for all the things that the one in VSC does. (I need it for C++)

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=akamud.vscode-theme-onedark

[image]

Comment: just look for the source code in the repository and copy the classes and colors to the format CLion wants

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated by rioV8, to get the exact behavior from Visual Studio's theme to CLION you have to copy the theme, as **there is no theme importer between Visual Studio Code and JetBrains CLion**.

The process to do so would be as follows:

1. **Get the source of your Visual Studio Color Scheme:**

   - You can get the source code from this repo ([VSCode There One Dark](https://github.com/akamud/vscode-theme-onedark)) and open it at your preferred editor or download it from the [Visual Studio Marketplace](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=akamud.vscode-theme-onedark).
2. **Customize your CLION's Theme:**

   - Select a Theme at Settings/Preferences
   - Clone using the Duplicate option at the config icon if you don't want to override the existing one
   - Enable/Edit the Semantic Highlighting: Editor -> Color Scheme -> Language Defaults -> Semantic highlighting.
   - Edit the Color Scheme by expanding the Editor -> Color Scheme and editing as you like.

You can find more detailed instructions at the docs: [Configuring colors and fonts](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/clion/configuring-colors-and-fonts.html)

** **Alternative:**
**You also can pick a similar JetBrains theme**; there are many apart from the default ones at the [JetBrains Plugins directory](https://plugins.jetbrains.com).
For example, this [JetBrains Dark theme similar to Atom One Dark](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/11938-one-dark-theme).

Comment: IntelliJ dark color is not intuitive at all. I wish there was a easy way to import the theme. Thx for the answer.